# Get DateRange List Mysq Betweenl start_date and end_date

Tags: mysql, sql

My Mysql table Structure is :-
[image]

I want To Output as :-

2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-07
2020-01-08
2020-01-09
2020-01-10
2020-01-11

Comment: what is the output ? start_date, entry_date or end_date?

Comment: Hello Tsaikoga, i want to outpur as datediff between start date and end date 2020-01-01
2020-01-02
2020-01-03
2020-01-07
2020-01-08
2020-01-09
2020-01-10
2020-01-11